# SQL Server : getting certain table names from query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, information-schema, tablename

Is it possible to display just certain table names in the query:

```
USE [WebContact] 

SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'memberEmails'
```

Most of the time I would need all the table names but there are curtain situations where I need just certain row names.

When I try doing the following:

```
USE [WebContact] 

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, ContactDateTime 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'memberEmails'
```

It tell me that

> Invalid column name 'ContactDateTime'

even though that is one of the row names.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: `ContactDateTime` *might* be a column **in YOUR table** `memberEmails` - but it's most certainly **NOT** a column in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column `ContactDateTime` may be a column in your table but it is not a column in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view.

Since it is not a column there, SQL Server is going to error out saying that it is invalid.

I think what you're trying to do is add another `WHERE` clause to your statement:

```
USE [WebContact] 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'memberEmails'
AND [COLUMN_NAME] = 'ContactDateTime'; -- Here!
```

Or if you want to add multiple columns...

```
USE [WebContact] 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'memberEmails'
AND [COLUMN_NAME] 
  IN ('ContactDateTime', 'column2', 'column3', ... 'column(n)'); -- Here!
```

Also see here for the case against using [INFORMATION_SCHEMAS](https://sqlblog.org/2011/11/03/the-case-against-information_schema-views).

Comment: That last example seems to be the one I needed. Thanks Shaneis!

Comment: ah...yeah...no problem...seriously though learn the joys that is `sys.columns` and `sys.tables` and leave `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to itself :)

Answer (score 2):

if ContactDateTime is a column that you are looking for in table memberEmails then you can do this

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'memberEmails'
and COLUMN_NAME='ContactDateTime'
```

Comment: Does this work with more than one row name? When I try to add another **and** it comes back with blank data.

Comment: in that case, you have to use the in syntax such as `select .... where...column_name in ('ContactDateTime','AnotherColumnName')`

Answer (score 0):

The view `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` don't have column name `ContactDateTime`. Please [read document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx) first